# How can I add a package to the default installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, package-management, default, default-programs

I want to add the xclip package as default package in Ubuntu. When I install Linux then xclip package should also be installed with it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to include programs in Ubuntu by default is by making your own distribution of Ubuntu. There is a tool for this called the Ubuntu Customization Kit, check it out.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/uck/

Answer (score 0):

If you think that xclip is a good enough program to be included in the ISO files, you may want to file a [MIR application](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MainInclusionProcess).